# Set toolbar title

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I am trying to set my toolbar title like so:

```
public class StatisticsPage extends Fragment  {

    public StatisticsPage(){}
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.statistics_pagelayout, container, false);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.statsSpin);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
                R.array.statspage, R.layout.dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My title");

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        // do whatever stuff you wanna do here
                        Fragment Fragment_one;
                        FragmentManager man= getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction tran = man.beginTransaction();
                        Fragment_one = new BreweryStatistics();
                        tran.replace(R.id.main, Fragment_one);//tran.
                        tran.addToBackStack(null);
                        tran.commit();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Fragment Fragment_two;
                        FragmentManager mantwo= getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction trantwo = mantwo.beginTransaction();
                        Fragment_two = new StyleStatistics();
                        trantwo.replace(R.id.main, Fragment_two);//tran.
                        trantwo.addToBackStack(null);
                        trantwo.commit();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Fragment Fragment_three;
                        FragmentManager manthree= getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction tranthree = manthree.beginTransaction();
                        Fragment_three = new TasteStatisticsPage();
                        tranthree.replace(R.id.main, Fragment_three);//tran.
                        tranthree.addToBackStack(null);
                        tranthree.commit();
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                // your code here
            }
        });

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String userName = prefs.getString("userName", null);
        String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);
        String url = "myURL";
        String userURLComp = "u=" + userID;

        url = url + userURLComp ;

        new getBasicStats(getActivity()).execute(url);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Basically this line in the above code does not work in the fragment:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My title");
```

Also How can I stop my app title from showing up in the app bar? I would also like to make the title white when I can set it.

Comment: Try adding getActivity() before the getSupportFragment

Comment: still says cannot resolve method getsuuportactionbar

Comment: What about? ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");

Comment: worked perfectly, can I theme it white some how?

Comment: I would ask a separate question for that. I'm going to answer this question instead of comments

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Change it to

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
```

You needed to tell the activity it is an `AppCompatActivity`.

Then you use `getActivity()` to get the main activity since you are in a fragment.

Then just set the title as usual.

Comment: if you happen to know how to change the color, i just posted  that question too

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: Sorry Kevin, I'll add more. Should've known.

Comment: is there a way to do this in an async task?

Comment: The easiest and simplest answer

Comment: Thanks, very easiest way

Answer (score 11):

In kotlin

```
(activity as? AppCompatActivity)?.supportActionBar?.title = "title"
```

`Edit:` Added null safe operator `?` to avoid `NullPointer` in case ActionBar not available

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can just do the following:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    getActivity().setTitle("My title");
}
```

I make the change in `onActivityCreated` because the Activity may have not been fully initialized yet in `onCreateView`. In `onActivityCreated` there is no risk of getting a `NullPointerException`.

**NOTE**: I am using an `AppCompatActivity` with a `Toolbar` and v4 `Fragments` associated to it.

Comment: Where is `onActivityCreated`? In the main activity or the fragment? I have a list in my main activity and when I click on a list item a fragment is opened and the toolbar title should change. My click handler is in the fragment; does it need to be moved to the activity?

Comment: @HEATH3N `onActivityCreated` is meant for the fragments, when `onActivityCreated` is called on the fragment, it means that its parent activity is fully initialized (no risk of null pointers).

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin set title from resources

Activity:

```
setTitle(R.string.some_title)
```

Fragment:

```
activity?.setTitle(R.string.some_title)
```

Answer (score 1):

The best and easiest way to do this, is to go to Android Manifest and change the `label` within the `Activity` section. This is what's responsible for labelling the Activity along the toolbar. This saves you writing lines of code in the class file.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin:

*in `onCreate` method* put `title = "Some Text Here"`

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me inside an activity. I haven't tried it inside fragment.

```
this.setTitle("welcome")
ActiviryName.this.setTitle("welcome");
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Also, you have a typo in `Activity`. BTW, how is this different from the other answers?