# Fragment to fragment communication within a NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, navigationview

In my app, I have a NavigationDrawer in my app that has two fragments I want to display (Fragment1 and Fragment2) in a MainActivity. I have a menu item in my ToolBar in Fragment 1 when clicked I want to my MainActivity to switch to Fragment2 and have the NavigationView reflect the UI changes.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private NavigationView nvDrawer;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, new BookListFragment()).commit();
        }

        // Set a Toolbar to replace the ActionBar.
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Find our drawer view
        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerToggle = setupDrawerToggle();

        // Tie DrawerLayout events to the ActionBarToggle
        mDrawer.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

        // Find our drawer view
        nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);
        // Setup drawer view
        setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle setupDrawerToggle() {
        // NOTE: Make sure you pass in a valid toolbar reference.  ActionBarDrawToggle() does not require it
        // and will not render the hamburger icon without it.
        return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
    }

    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }

    public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
        // Create a new fragment and specify the fragment to show based on nav item clicked
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass;
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.book_list_fragment:
                fragmentClass = BookListFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.discover_fragment:
                fragmentClass = DiscoverFragment.class;
                break;
            default:
                fragmentClass = BookListFragment.class;
        }

        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

        // Highlight the selected item has been done by NavigationView
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        // Set action bar title
        setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
        // Close the navigation drawer
        mDrawer.closeDrawers();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
        }

        if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Fragment Code

```
public class BookListFragment extends Fragment  {
    ... 
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_insert_dummy_data:
                insertBook();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_delete_all_entries:
                int rowsDeleted = getContext().getContentResolver().delete(ShelfHelpContract.BookEntry.CONTENT_URI, null, null);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_discover:
                /*TODO Here I want to open another Fragment and have it reflect 
                in the UI on my NavigationView and MainActivity
                */

                return true;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    ....
}
```

Comment: "have the NavigationView reflect the UI changes" What UI changes?

Comment: In the NavigationView I want the UI to show that it changed drawer menu items, not just replace my current fragment with a new one.

Comment: Actually, you should just navigate by setting the selected item on the navigation view. The listener should handle the navigation to the fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code takes care of replacing your `Fragment` when the user clicks on one of the navigation items

```
// Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();
```

Besides replacing the fragment you will want to also [update the title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954445/set-toolbar-title) of your activity using something along the lines of:

`((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");`

And finally you must tell your `NavigationView` to highlight the right item using the `setChecked(boolean)` function. It should look something like this:

`nvDrawer.getMenu().findItem(/*your item id*/).setChecked(true);`

If you want to perform the same action when the user clicks on a menu item then make sure to add a new case to the switch block found in your `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` and just call the same lines passing in the right `Fragment`

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the response. That implementation switches to the right fragment but the changes don't appear in the navigationview. It still shows that I'm in my initial fragment.

Comment: Do you mean that the navigation view highlights a different screen than the one you're currently viewing?

Comment: I believe so. Here's an [example](https://flic.kr/p/Vu6DjC) of what I want to do and an [example](https://flic.kr/p/VPtuEY) of what I have happening.